# confuse about reference and functions c++

Tags: c++

If I have a function reference

```
string& Basic_Functions::printval(std::string &str){
  return str;
}
```

Then I called it in main

```
 string  sample = "This is a sample";
 cout << sample<< endl;
```

What does printval function refer to?

I tried modifying the function and make it like this

```
string Basic_Functions::printval2(std::string &str){
  return str;
}

string& Basic_Functions::printval3(std::string str){
  return str;
}
```

And in my main

```
string i2 = printval2(sample) = "hehe"; 

cout << i2 << endl;

string i3 = printval3(sample) = "huhuh";
cout << i3 << endl;
```

Function printval2 is easy to understand. What I can't understand is printval() and printval3().

In the book I am reading a sample of reference is like:

```
string hey = "hello"; string &woah = hey // woah is a reference to
                                         // hey. meaning it is bound to hey.
```

but if you say

```
string i3 = printval(sample) = "huhuh"; //?
```

What am I referencing here? What is the printval() bound to?

Comment: This is really badly formatted.  Please fix.

Comment: "*if i have a function reference*" - that's not a function reference. "*called it on main*" - you didn't call it. "*I tried modifying the function*" - you didn't modify it. You created two new ones. All in all, go back to your book.

Comment: @Tifa In the first example you do not call a function. You simply print out the string itself.

Comment: It would seem like you could do with reading a basic C++ book. There is a wonderful reference on this site already.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, a bunch of problems. From the top:

```
string& Basic_Functions::printval(std::string& str) {
    return str;
}
```

This is *not* a function reference, it is the definition of a function taking a reference to `std::string` and returning a reference to `string` (I'm assuming you meant `std::string` and not a custom class?). This function will return the same instance of `std::string` that is passed to it, e.g.

```
std::string s1 = "Sample string";
std::string s2 = Basic_Functions::printval(s1); // Equal to "std::string s2 = s1";
```

Next:

```
std::string sample = "This is a sample";
std::cout << sample << std::endl;
```

This uses the `<<` operator to output the `std::string` object `sample` to the standard output stream `std::cout`. It has nothing to do with the previously defined function `printval`.

In the following function definitions `printval2` and `printval3` you have changed the return type to return by value (return a copy), respective changed the parameter type to take by value (argument is copied). As the purpose of the first function is not clear and seems a bit useless, the second and third version doesn't make much sense either.

Next we find something truly weird

```
string i2 = printval2(sample) = "hehe";
```

As `printval2` returns by value, this is equal to:

```
string i2 = (string(sample) = "hehe");
```

This will create a temporary using `sample` and assign `"hehe"` to it, then it will initialize `i2` with the temporary. This is really unnecessary work as you get the same effect with a simple `string i2 = "hehe"`.

The third variant `printval3` introduces *undefined behaviour* as it returns a local variable by reference.

```
string& Basic_Functions::printval3(std::string str) { // Argument is copy constructed.
    return str; // Returning a reference to something that will soon be destructed.
} // All local variables are destructed here.
```

E.g.

```
const std::string& sref = printval3(sample); // Store reference.
cout << sref << endl;                        // UB! sref points to deallocated data.
```

Finally

```
string i3 = printval(sample) = "huhuh"; //?
```

This is equal to

```
string i3 = (sample = "huhuh");
```

`printval` returns a reference to `sample` which is then assigned to with `"huhuh"`, and finally `i3` is initialized with `sample`. This is basically the same as doing

```
sample = "huhuh";
string i3 = sample;
```